# VS 2017 15.3.3 Not Responding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created an Asp.Net Core 2.0 WebApi application using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3.3. Whenever I add, edit or delete files from the Solution Explorer, VS freezes for an indeterminate time (2 - 120 seconds), before becoming responsive again.

I have followed all the suggestions from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30723/visual-studio-2017-too-slow-for-use.html, but with no success.

I was hoping someone had a solution to this problem, so that I do not have to send a trace to the Visual Studio Team.

It should be noted that I have ReSharper Ultimate and Web Essentials installed, but the problem persisted after disabling them both.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as you today and it was driving me crazy.

Eventually I did a **`dotnet restore`** in a command prompt in the web application directory. This solved the long freezes for me. Before the 'restore' adding/removing files took one minute or more, now it only takes 1 second. It could still be better but it is workable now.

*Update*: the web project I work on has two `node_modules` folders: one in the project root and one in a subdirectory. When I delete the one in the subfolder the IDE becomes even more responsive. So it looks seems that a Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core web project gets a performance hit when there are a lot of files/subdirectories in the project files. And 'node_modules' is - alas - a directory that grows very fast in size...

*Update 2*: You can exclude extra folders by adding the `<DefaultItemExcludes>` property to the .csproj file, like `<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);ClientLib\node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>`. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice of David Urting and ran **dotnet restore** to no avail.

My solution also has a client folder containing an angular 4 application, with another node_modules folder.

I removed the client application from WebApApi solution and moving it into the same folder as the .sln file, which is where my git repository is.

When I run **ng build --prod** (angular cli), I move the distribution files into the www folder of the web application.

The freezing/not responding has ceased.

It should be noted that I removed the node_module folders from the solution also, but this did not help either.

Comment: I was finally able to keep one project with mutiple **node_modules** folders by adding a `DefaultItemExcludes` property to the .csproj file eg. `<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);ClientLib\node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>`.